# How do you annotate for custom classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, pycharm

Say that I have a class, `Shard`, and my return value for a method should be a `list` of `Shard` objects.

```
my_method(args) -> ??:
```

Pycharm kicks up an error when I imported `List` from `typing` and specified `List[Shard]` (the error is related to it not being able to find Shard).

Here is the method in question:

```
def _return_shards(self, sql: str = None) -> List[Shard]:
        """
        Queries the database to return a sequence of all the database clusters
        and shards, and then creates Shard objects with the information.

        @type conn_info: dict
        :param conn_info: Database information containing the host, port, user,
         database, and password.
         @type sql: str

        :return: A list of Shard items
        """
        logging.info('Creating shards.')
        cursor = self._return_cursor(self.canvas_conn)

        stock_query = '''
              SELECT
                database_server_id || 'dr' database_server_id
              , CASE
                  WHEN database_server_id LIKE 'cluster1' AND name IS NULL THEN 'canvas'
                  WHEN database_server_id LIKE 'cluster4' AND name IS NULL THEN 'canvas'
                  WHEN name IS NULL THEN database_server_id
                  ELSE name
                END AS database_name
                ,SUBSTRING(database_server_id FROM '\d+$')::INT cluster_id
                ,CASE
                  WHEN name IS NULL THEN SUBSTRING(database_server_id FROM '\d+$')::INT
                  ELSE SUBSTRING(name FROM '\d+$')::INT
                END AS shard_id
              FROM canvas.switchman_shards
              WHERE database_server_id LIKE 'cluster%'
              ORDER BY cluster_id, shard_id
              '''
        if sql:
            cursor.execute(sql)
        else:
            cursor.execute(stock_query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        self._set_reporter_total_shards(count=len(results))
        return [Shard(
            *result,
            job=self.job,
            manifest=self.manifest,
            reporter=self.reporter.create_slave(db=result[0], schema=result[1])
        ) for result in results]
```

The error is `NameError: name 'Shard' is not defined` even though the `Shard` class is defined in the same module.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It needs a [mcve].

Comment: What error? Is `Shard` in scope?

Comment: I've added the method and error in question.

Comment: Given the `self`, are you *inside* the definition of `Shard`?

Comment: No, now I realize it's because Shard is defined below this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shard` isn't defined yet, either because you're still in the middle of the class definition, or because `Shard` is defined below this class. [Give the name as a string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

```
def _return_shards(self, sql: str = None) -> List['Shard']:
```